# How to speed up a writing and reading speed from data mart via splitting it into multiple parts in data warehouse and use it in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, obiee

In our datawarehouse, we have a huge and one of the most used and important table, that stores account data(their ids, saldo corresponding to operational day, etc). On a daily basis, approximately 90 mln rows are loaded into this table. Table is composite partitioned, with interval of Month on column OPER_DAY and list subpartitions on column FILIAL. The table has 9 indexes, 6 of which are Bitmap.

Loading this amount of data is already taking lots of time, around 2 hours, we do bulk collect and use APPEND_VALUES hint to get advantage of a direct path insert. We also specify nologging for a table but since force logging is enabled this doesn't impact at all.

Currenty table has data for 3 years. Reading part is also becoming an issue, if an OBIEE user queries this table to get info on one day (sum of saldo for one day for example) , then it is working fast, but if a user wants to see for a month or two, then it is getting much slower.

Is there any way I can split a table into multiple tables, each of which will store only one year's data and include them all in a new view with union alls? Each select of a union will have a condition so that if user queries data of 2023 then only one select of a union will be executed, if he runs for 2022 and 2023 then two selects inside union will be executed and so on? Therefore, there wouldn't be a need to scan whole table, only required table after splitting will be selected.

Main problem we are facing with this approach is we don't know what filter on calendar an OBIEE user wil set in an analysis. We had an idea to use SYS_CONTEXT, and set context parameters for a session, but we couldn't find a way to set context from OBIEE filters, we did only for session variables by setting them with dashboard prompt. Is it possible or what could be another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can split a table into multiple tables, each of which will store only one year's data

This is what partitioning does (at the database level) and you are already using partitioning at month level.   Assuming `OPER_DAY` is going to be filtered in user queries then you should already be getting partition elimination taking place to cut down the amount of data being read.

## Database

If you are loading 90 millions records a day then you have a lot of data so it is going to take some time to load and query.    There are plenty of things you can do about loading the data but performance tuning is dependant on your system and code it is impossible to give you anything particularly useful only generic advice.

First off I am assuming at that volume you have hardware to cope?   You are running things in parallel and on RAC?  You haven't mentioned it so I assume you are not using Exadata.

I am guessing that at 90 million records a day the data is primarily (only?) new and insert rather than update?   If so your first bottleneck will be that all the data is new so you are hitting the same segments for all data.   Depending on the distribution of `FILIAL` that sub-partitioning could be hindering you rather then helping.
If it is insert only check that the execution plan is actually doing a direct path insert.   You can put all the hints in you like but if direct path isn't possible you aren't going to get the benefits.

Depending on what you are licensed for, advanced compression may help too.

Indexes don't always help.   If they aren't being used you are just introducing bottlenecks of updating the indexes for the sake of it.

Ultimately you need to look at where the database is doing and where the bottlnecks are and then look for solutions.

## BI

There are lots of things you can do but I suspect trying to segment things will only cause you problems elsewhere.   If you really want to do it then look at fragmentation.

I suspect that reports do not need all the data, they are aggregating up and removing columns.   The best option for reporting speed is to create aggregates and add these as separate logical table sources.   This is all invisible to the user but if their query can be satisfied by an existing aggregate that will get used and will massively reduce response times.

Beyond that you are back to performance tuning which sounds like it will likely be database tuning again and looking at the explain plan of physical queries and looking where they can be improved.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply. As you guessed, we do not use Exadata and RAC. We have advanced compression, so table and its partitions are compressed using advanced compression. 90 millions rows are indeed new , so only insert is performed. However, defining new is tricky in this table, because this table holds accounts' saldo for each operating day. That is it is possible that out of 90 millions only 10 million accounts have been changed during a day, they will have  new values, other 80 million will have same values as for previos oper_day, only oper_day column value would be different

Comment: I am not sure of the reporting requirements but I can't see that this is a good way of doing things.   You say you have one record per day but that people are reporting over months.  If you are adding the same record every day you cannot have any aggregable measures.   You r reporting layer should be structured around reporting requirements not the data source.    Also if only 11% change a day then you are storing 25 billion duplicate records each yea which seems excessive.   It sounds like you are just loading the data as it comes which is going to cause you these issues.